# Does AVFoundation do better color adjustment than CoreImage?

Tags: avfoundation, core-image, ios-camera

I want to do some extreme, custom color temperature adjustments within an iPhone app and I'm trying to understand: what is the difference between doing it with AVFoundation vs with CoreImage filters?

When you shoot photos with RAW, then the RAW file records more image information from the camera sensor than a JPEG file or even a lossless format like TIFF. I thought it was *because of this* that you could only do true after-the-fact white-balancing with RAW files, and this [Canon spokesman seems to think so too](http://www.thephoblographer.com/2011/09/26/are-tiffs-and-raws-really-the-same-thing/#6tRwPE5voEKTxOLD.99).

Since iOS does not give you access to a RAW-like representation of the camera data, I presumed that you need to do color temperature and tint adjustments using the iOS camera system itself, at the moment of capture. AVFoundation provides API for this, introduced with iOS8. It lets you [query a device for its supported range of color temperature adjustments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureDevice/deviceWhiteBalanceGainsForTemperatureAndTintValues:), via `deviceWhiteBalanceGainsForTemperatureAndTintValues(_:)`. (This lets you use a temperature/tint pair to compute a white balance gain, and the device reports its allowed maximum white balance gain.)

However, Core Image [also provides API for adjusting the color temperature](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CITemperatureAndTint) of images, via `CITemperatureAndTint`. This confuses me, because Core Image does not require RAW data or have privileged access to the device's camera system.

If you can only do true white balance and color temperature adjustments with RAW data, and iOS does not give you this information, then how can Core Image do it at all? And furthermore, if AVFoundation allows different adjustments depending on the device, then how can Core Image do it in a device independent way?

Is Core Image doing just a rough approximation of what AVFoundation is doing better and with more data? Or are the AVFoundation white balance routines just high-level wrappers for the existing Core Image filters?

I suppose another way of asking this is to ask if AVFoundation's color correction routines are benefiting from privileged access to sensor data I could not access myself, using relatively low-level API like `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(_:completionHandler:)` and `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer`.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. CoreImage will do the white balance etc. with the information it has so there will be a definite loss of fidelity. If I was you I'd try both and look at the quality of the results. AVFoundation will likely be faster as well as better quality.

Comment: I doubt my eyeballs can tell the difference, which may mean I shouldn't sweat the difference, but the app is for people with a professional interest in these subtleties, so maybe they can. The puzzle is that nothing in the API docs actually states that AVFoundation's white balance methods are using data that you cannot get elsewhere. I'm inferring that from my understanding of RAW vs TIFF/JPEG, but the more I think on it the more I realize I don't understand _exactly_ what makes RAW specia so this could be a bad inference.